# Configuring SSL certificate for SharePoint 2013 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: ssl, sharepoint-server, certificate, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to configure my SSL certificate for my SharePoint site. I'm using this site : [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/fabdulwahab/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013)
I'm stuck on step 2 I can't seem to find manage compute certificate anywhere on the server. Where can I find this?

---

Open command prompt and run certmgr.msc
Now it doesn't show the SharePoint node like explaind in the tutorial. How can I add the SharePoint folder as default?

Answer (score 2):

You have to open the **Manage Computer Certificates** which is *certlm.msc* (and not *certmgr.msc*). There youll find the SharePoint node.

I'm running Windows Server 2012.

Screenshots for demonstration.
[image: Screenshot for demonstration]

Comment: Typically SSL certs go in Personal under Local Computer.  SharePoint is for the SharePoint cert trust and not IIS SSL certs.

Answer (score 1):

For those like me who can't find certlm.msc on their Windows 2008 **R2** server :

1. Execute mmc.exe
2. Click on file > Add/Delete
3. Choose the "certificate" and click on "Add"
4. Then select the "A computer account"

And you are done, you can see all nodes of the Local Machine certificates.